# Cannot add a method to a button click event C# UWP

Tags: c#, uwp-xaml

I have some problems making the HangMan game to work. Since i got my buttons, i had to make a method that displays the alphabet letters to user. So i have this Guessing method what i want to add to a button click event. So i get this red squiqqly line when i try to add a method to a button. The error is in HangMan_OnLoaded method. Thanks!
[image: HangmangGame][image: Problem]

```
        public void DisplayTheWord()
    {
        WrongGuesses = 0;
        BitmapImage Hangman2 = new BitmapImage();
        Uri URL = new Uri(BaseUri, images[WrongGuesses]);
        Hangman2.UriSource = URL;
        picture.Source = Hangman2;
        string[] ReadWords = File.ReadAllLines("EnglishWords.txt");
        int NextNumber = (new Random().Next(words.Length));
        copyCurrent = "";
        current = words[NextNumber];

        for (int i = 0; i < ReadWords[NextNumber].Length; i++)
        {
            copyCurrent += "_" + "   ";
        }
        CopiedWord.Text = copyCurrent;
    }
    private void Hangman_OnLoaded()
    {
        const int btnSize = 35;
        var c = 0;
        for (var i = 65; i <= 90; i++)
        {
            var btn = new Button();
            btn.Content = (char)i;
            btn.Width = btn.Height = btnSize;
            var margin = btn.Margin;
            margin.Left = c += 37;
            btn.Margin = margin;
            GridMain.Children.Add(btn);
            btn.Click += Guessing();
        }

    }
    private void Guessing(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (var i = 65; i <= 90; i++)
        {
            var btn = new Button();
            btn = sender as Button;
            btn.Content = (char) i;
            var choice = btn.ToString();
            if (copyCurrent.Contains(choice))
            {
                char[] temp = copyCurrent.ToCharArray();
                char[] find = current.ToCharArray();
                char guessChar = choice.ElementAt(0);
                for (int index = 0; index < find.Length; index++)
                {
                    if (find[index]== guessChar)
                    {
                        temp[index] = guessChar;
                    }
                }
                copyCurrent = new string(temp);
            }
            else
            {
                WrongGuesses++;
            }
            if (WrongGuesses < 6)
            {

            }
        }
    }

    private void DisplayCopy()
    {
        CopiedWord.Text = "";
        for (int index = 0; index < copyCurrent.Length; index++)
        {
            CopiedWord.Text += copyCurrent.Substring(index, 1);
            CopiedWord.Text += " ";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Remove the brackets: `btn.Click += Guessing;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@swatsonpicken said right. you need to remove the brackets from the line:

```
btn.Click += Guessing();
```

and replace with:

```
btn.Click += Guessing;
```

And one more thing you will need to correct that is the

```
private void Guessing(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Write above line as below:

```
private void Guessing(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
```

Hope this will help. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the brackets from the line:

```
btn.Click += Guessing();
```

so that it becomes:

```
btn.Click += Guessing;
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks for answering. When i remove the brackets, it says : No overload for 'Guessing' matches delegate 'RoutedEventHandler'. Expected a method with 'void Guessing(object, RoutedEventArgs)' signature.

Comment: Have you tried acting on what the error message is telling you, i.e. changing the method signature of Guessing to accept a RoutedEventArgs (rather than an EventArgs type) type for the second parameter?

Answer (score 0):

I think:

The error is because Guessing is void and dont return nothing but yor're using Guessing like a method that return a event:

`btn.Click += Guessing();`

For dix that return a value event :)

Comment: Hello! What do u mean by returning a value event? Thank you!

Comment: Yes, try to do something like this, return the value `RoutedEventArgs e` and edit the method param `EventArgs` to `RoutedEventArgs` remember change `void`to `RoutedEventArgs` :). Hope help you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your handler fits to Event you want to use:

```
private void Guessing(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
   //your handler code
}

btn.Click += Guessing;
```

Reason for that is, each event is expecting signature of delegate and defines parameters.